# Add the Fibonnaci Sequence to the Lucas Sequence

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence, fibonacci, subsequence

**Background of Lucas Numbers**

The French mathematician, Edouard Lucas (1842-1891), who gave the name to the Fibonacci Numbers, found a similar series occurs often when he was investigating Fibonacci number patterns.

The Fibonacci rule of adding the latest two to get the next is kept, but here we start from 2 and 1 (in this order) instead of 0 and 1 for the (ordinary) Fibonacci numbers.
The series, called the Lucas Numbers after him, is defined as follows: where we write its members as Ln, for Lucas:

[image]

**Challenge**

**Input**

0 < x < ∞
The input will be a positive integer starting at 0.

**Output**

The output must be a positive integer.

**What to do?**

Add the Fibonacci numbers to the Lucas numbers.
You will input the index.
The output will be the addition of the Lucas and Fibonacci numbers.

**Fibonnaci formula:**

> F(0) = 0,
>   F(1) = 1,
>   F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2)

**Lucas formula:**

> L(0) = 2,
>   L(1) = 1,
>   L(n) = L(n-1) + L(n-2)

**Who wins?**

Standard Code-Golf rules apply, so the shortest answer in bytes wins.

**Test-cases**

> A(0)  = 2
>   A(1)  = 2
>   A(5)  = 16
>   A(10) = 178
>   A(19) = 13,530
>   A(25) = 242,786

Comment: This is just twice the Fibonacci numbers, with a different offset. (L[n] = F[n–1] + F[n+1], so L[n] + F[n] = 2F[n+1].) I'm tempted to call it a duplicate.

Comment: @Belfield I'm not sure I follow. This *is* just 2F[n+1]. The Mathematica answer `2Fibonacci[#+1]&` solves the challenge.

Comment: Yes, didnt see that @Lynn

Answer (score 1):

## C, 33 bytes

```c
A(n){return n<2?2:A(n-1)+A(n-2);}
```

Comment: Why is there no `int`?

Comment: It’s implicit in very-old-style C.

Comment: @KritixiLithos there is no need, compiler adds it. The original K&R C didn't have it, this is just for backward compatibility.